# Make second API call with attributes already obtained - Facebook Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, hash

I'm unsure on how to approach the next part of my API call with Facebook. At the moment I am retrieving all the posts using a user ID:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/#{VANDALS_ID}/posts/?access_token=#{FB_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
```

But I would also like to get the picture associated with each post by using the object_id that is returned from the first API call:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/#{object_id}/picture
```

So at the moment I have a class that handles the first API call and then saves the returned data into my model:

```
class FacebookFeed
#Constants
VANDALS_ID = ENV['VANDALS_FB_ID']
FB_ACCESS_TOKEN = ENV['FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN']
FACEBOOK_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{VANDALS_ID}/posts/?access_token=#{FB_ACCESS_TOKEN}"

def get_feed
  uri = URI(FACEBOOK_URL)
  response = HTTParty.get(uri)
  results = JSON.parse(response.body)
  puts formatted_data(results)
end

def formatted_data(results)
  
 return unless results

    results['data'].map { |m| 
    attrs = { message: m['message'], 
              picture: m['picture'], 
              link: m['link'], 
              object_id: m['object_id']
      }.compact 
      
     
     Post.where(attrs).first_or_create! do |post|
        post.attributes = attrs
     end
   }
   end

  def get_large_photo(object_id)
  #added this to handle the second api request and pass through the object_id

  end
```

So all the information I want from the first API call is in a hash called attrs, which I can then access the object_id via `attrs['object_id']`. Is that correct?

I'm stuck on how to get each object_id out of the hash and get the picture associated with it in a separate call, and then save the value assigned to the key :picture and put it back into my attrs hash so that I can save everything in my post model.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this, although I'm still confused as to what you're trying to achieve:

```
def formatted_data(results)
    if results[:data]
        for record in results[:data] do
             attrs = {
                 message: record[:message],
                 picture: record[:picture],
                 link: record[:link],
                 object_id: record[:object_id]
             }
             Post.where(attrs).first_or_create!(attrs)

             #perform second call
             if record[:object_id]
                post = Post.find_by object_id: record[:object_id] 
                if post
                    fb_large_picture_url = get_large_photo(record[:object_id])
                    post.update_attribute(large_image_url: fb_large_picture_url)
                end
             end
        end
    end
 end

 def get_large_photo(object_id)
     uri = URI("https://graph.facebook.com/#{object_id}/picture")
     response = HTTParty.get(uri)
     results = JSON.parse(response.body)
     return formatted_picture_data(results) #new method to handle response from second api call
 end
```

After discussing with Rich on Skype, it seems the real problem is he's trying to amend the db to have records with `object_id` to call the API again, posting a larger image

This is quite inefficient, but still should work

Answer (score 0):

There are a great gem for interacting with FB API - [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala). It has very good Wiki page on github.

With this gem it is very easy to get all the information you need. 
You can use `graph.get_connections` or `graph.get_object` to get what you want.

Here is an example:

```
gem 'koala', "~> 1.8.0rc1"
require 'koala'
require 'pp'

user_access_token = 'access_token_here'
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user_access_token) 

pp books_raw = graph.get_connections('me', 'books') 
# pp likes_raw = graph.get_connection('me', 'likes')

books_ids_array, books_names_array = [], [] 

books_raw.each_with_index {|element, i|
  puts "id: #{books_raw[i]['id']} \n\t name: #{books_raw[i]['name']}"
  books_ids_array << books_raw[i]['id'] 
  books_names_array << books_raw[i]['name']
}

books_ids_array.each {|node|
  pp book_page = graph.get_object(node)
}
puts
```

Answer (score 0):

So a big thanks goes to Rich Peck for his assistance , after chatting (for a few hours :-) ) and learning all about `Rails.logger.info()`, `return` and many other things we have a working solution, albeit not the most efficient but it works.

This is what the Class now looks like, if anyone has any re-factoring tips then they would be greatly appreciated

```
require 'httparty'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

class FacebookFeed
#Constants
VANDALS_ID = ENV['VANDALS_FB_ID']
FB_ACCESS_TOKEN = ENV['FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN']
FACEBOOK_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{VANDALS_ID}/posts/?access_token=#{FB_ACCESS_TOKEN}"

def get_feed
  uri = URI(FACEBOOK_URL)
  response = HTTParty.get(uri)
  results = JSON.parse(response.body)
  return formatted_data(results)  
end

def formatted_data(results)
  if results['data']
    for record in results['data'] do
         attrs = {
             message: record['message'],
             picture: record['picture'],
             link: record['link'],
             object_id: record['object_id']
         }

         Post.where(attrs).first_or_create! do |post|
          post.attributes = attrs
         end

         #perform second call
         if record['object_id']
            post = Post.find_by object_id: record['object_id']
            if post
                fb_large_picture_url = get_large_photo(record['object_id'])
                post.update_column(:large_image_url, fb_large_picture_url)
            end
         end
      end
   end
end

 def get_large_photo(object_id)
   second_uri = URI("https://graph.facebook.com/#{object_id}/?picture")
   second_response = HTTParty.get(second_uri)
   second_results = JSON.parse(second_response)
   return formatted_picture_data(second_results)
 end

 def formatted_picture_data(second_results)
   return second_results['source']
 end

end
```